# Transform map coordinates to page coordinate in ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, convert, java, coordinates

I have a map inside a page layout in ArcMap.
Currently, I use this code to convert geographic coordinates to page coordinates:

```
    IMap map = ...
IPageLayout pageLayout = ...

IDisplayTransformation mapTransformation = ((IActiveView)map).getScreenDisplay().getDisplayTransformation();
IDisplayTransformation pageTransformation = ((IActiveView)pageLayout).getScreenDisplay().getDisplayTransformation();

IPoint mapPoint = ...

int x[] = {0};
int y[] = {0};
mapTransformation.fromMapPoint(mapPoint, x, y);
IPoint pagePoint = pageTransformation.toMapPoint(x[0], y[0]);
```

For example, if mapPoint = 913767.624037, 6458100.4284 (in meters)

I get:
**x[0], y[0] = 18, -2**

Then: pagePoint = 18.0, 2.0 (in centimeters

The problem is that x[0], y[0] are intergers as the method [IDisplayTransformation.fromMapPoint](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/display/IDisplayTransformation.html) return integers (for device pixels). Their values are corrects but they are rounded. I would expect for this example a pagePoint = 18.42 cm, 2.19 cm

What's wrong in my conversion method?
Is there an other way to make this conversion with more precision?

Comment: I don't think these are in cm but in device units aka pixels...or maybe points (a printing unit).

Comment: Yes these are in pixels if you are in ArcMap. But in my case, I'm in a Java console, without any window, and what I get for x[] and y[] are centimeters rounded to smallest integer.